# Why does C not require a garbage collector?

Tags: c, garbage-collection

My understanding of this has come down to C's origins as a "portable assembler" and the option of less overhead. Is thiat all there is to it?

Comment: C doesn't need a garbage collector because...you are it.  This is what `free` is for.

Comment: C doesn't produce garbage.

Comment: @KerrekSB - Yes it does.  Or at least, a badly written C program does.

Comment: @StephenC: That'd be *programmers* producing garbage :-S

Comment: Why do you think it should?

Comment: Why do other languages "require" garbage collectors?

Comment: Well, I suspect its to avoid memory mismanagement, dangling references, etc. but why was it decided to have manual mangement over a GC?

Comment: Languages are like vehicles: some have training wheels, seat beats, air bags, padded sides, helmets, GPS, radios.  C does not.  http://crashworks.org/if_programming_languages_were_vehicles/

Comment: I think C does not have garbage collector because nobody has written one. If there is a garbage collector for C, everybody would use it. All allocated memories need to be freed. If a programming language has garbage collector we use them. Otherwise programmer has to write code for it.

Comment: @StephenC: To make that more precise, the programs that you have in mind do not require a garbage collector, they require *fixing*. C doesn't by itself produce garbage, rather, it exposes all the resource allocations to the programmer and allows the programmer to deal with them deterministically and deliberately. That may or may not be prone to bugs, but it does not *require* a runtime system for correctness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, lets be clear about what garbage is.

The Java definition of garbage is objects that are no longer reachable.  The precise meaning of reachable is a bit abstruse, but a practical definition is that if you can get to an object by following references (pointers) from well known places like thread stacks or static variables, then it *may be* reachable.  (In practice, some imprecision is OK, so long as objects that *are* reachable don't get deleted.)

You could try to apply the same definition to C and C++.  An object is garbage if it cannot be reached.

However, the practical problem with this definition ... and garbage collection ... in C or C++ is whether a "pointer like" value is actually a valid pointer.  For instance:

- An uninitialized C variable can contain a random value that looks like a pointer to an object.
- When a C `union` type that overlays a pointer with an `long`, a garbage collector cannot be sure whether the union contains one or the other ... or both.
- When C application code "compresses" pointers to word aligned heap nodes by dividing them by 4 or 8, a garbage collector won't detect them as "pointer like".  Or if it does, it will misinterpret them.
- A similar issues is when C application code represents pointers as offsets relative to something else.

However, it is clear that a C program can call `malloc`, forget to call `free`, and then forget the address of the heap node.  That node is garbage.

---

There are two reasons why C / C++ doesn't have garbage collection.

- It is "culturally inappropriate".  The culture of these languages is to leave storage management to the programmer.
- It would be technically difficult (and expensive) to implement a *precise* garbage collector for C / C++.  Indeed, doing this would involve things that made the language implementation slow.
- Imprecise (i.e. conservative) garbage collectors are practical, but they have performance and (I have heard) reliability issues.  (For instance, a conservative collector cannot move non-garbage objects.)

It would be simpler if the implementer (of a C / C++ garbage collector) could assume that the programmer only wrote code that strictly conformed to the C / C++ specs.  But they don't.

---

But your answer seems to be, why did they design C like that?

Questions like that can only be answered authoritatively by the designers  (in this case, the late Dennis Ritchie) or their writings.

As you point out in the question, C *was* designed to be simple and "close to the hardware".

However, C was designed in the early 1970's.  In those days programming languages which required a garbage collector were rare, and GC techniques were not as advanced as they are now.

And even now, it is still a fact that garbage collected languages (like Java) are not suitable for applications that require predictable "real-time" performance.

In short, I suspect that the designers were of the view that garbage collection would make the language impractical for its intended purpose.

Comment: The problem list is not complete. Real life example: the C code takes the pointer of allocated memory, divides it by four, and stores it into a structure that must stay backward compatible to some old bcpl code (or to other C code that had to use that structure for the same reasons). Whenever the memory needs to be accessed, the value is multiplied by four right before the access, otherwise, the actual pointer never occurs in memory. Other example, the pointers to a certain structure were always pointing to some embedded structure, the allocated memory always started a known offset before that

Comment: Addressed those points ...

Answer (score 1):

There are some garbage collectors built for C or C++:
Please check http://www.hboehm.info/gc/.

As you stated, garbage collection defies the purpose of performance claimed by C and C++, as it requires tracking allocations and/or reference counting.